# String concatenation time complexity c++

Tags: c++, string, time-complexity, stringstream, stdstring

I have searched different ways of concatenating strings in C++ and I found std::stringstream and std::string as possible options. However, I could not find a time complexity for the concatenation operations for both stringstream and string. What is the time complexity of string concatenation in C++. Moreover, what are the time complexities for converting to string in both std::stringstream and std::string in C++. Is it possible to append strings in 0(1) time in C++? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The 'time-complexities' are of the same order O(N). But adding two `std::string` objects together will be a great deal faster than using `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Think about it: you can't go sub-linear because of copying required; it goes one char at a time. You cannot also go super-linear, because there are no nested loops during concatenation. Hence, O(n+m) is the only thing that's left.

Comment: std::stringstream however is much better at converting to strings right?

Comment: Converting a string to a string?

Comment: no so if I have an int then is a std::stringstream better at converting the int to a string or not?

Comment: I would expect linear complexity (in characters count) for `ss << a << b << c << .. << z` or `res = a; res += b; .. res += z` over a quadratic complexity for `res = a + b + c + .. + z`. The last one naively doing `(((a + b) + c) + ..) + z`

Comment: How can Java's stringbuffer append in 0(1) amortized-time?

Answer (score 0):

Both are unspecified, but you can guess at linear complexity (create new buffer, copy the chars to the new buffer).

Comment: No but in C++ you can just append to both std::string and std::stringstream so in that case would it still be linear complexity?

Comment: @VishwaPatel yes. Both are doing almost the same thing, probably the stringstream needs 2 copies but it's still linear time.

Comment: So would it be efficient to use std::string for appending and std::stringstream for converting to strings?

Comment: @VishwaPatel std::string to appending string-string and std::stringstream for "complex" appends (like string-integer, string-float).

Comment: Thanks a lot @amchacon

Comment: So appending a character is also O(N)?

Comment: @VishwaPatel depends if it needs resize the buffer or not.